# Compare the call graph of two apk files using soot

Tags: java, android, soot

I am trying to make a program that will

1. Take an apk file as input
2. Convert it into dalvik byte code
3. than later from dalvik bytecode to jimple
4. Will generate the call graph of the program
5. Process the call graph of a Program and will try to match it with the already existing programs to find the degree of similarity amongst the two.

Basically it will be comparing the callgraph of a program with a call graph of a malware. I planned to use soot to do so.
Presently i am planning to write the code in java and am working on windows platform

Please provide some suitable ways. If code is available,that will be even better.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Look at PROBE:
http://plg.uwaterloo.ca/~olhotak/probe/

It allows you to compare Soot-based call graphs.